# How can I play and pause a default COLLADA animation at certain keyframes?

Tags: scenekit, caanimation

I want to play and pause an animation in FBX format. I couldn't find a way to make that work, so I first convert the `fbx` files to `dae` (COLLADA) format, which can be imported for use in SceneKit.

I am loading the `dae` file like this, and adding it to an `ARAnchor` that has been detected by ARKit (I don't think it's relevant that I am loading it in an AR app).

```
func createNode() -> SCNNode {
    let node = SCNNode()

    // Instantiate the file
    let scene = SCNScene(named: file)!

    // Steal all their children
    scene.rootNode.childNodes.forEach { node.addChildNode($0) }

    // Scale the node
    node.scale = SCNVector3(scale, scale, scale)

    return node
}
```

Now the animation that is contained in the original `fbx` file plays, which is nice. Now I want to pause it, and eventually play only selected frames of the animation (to show the animation in different steps, when the user clicks a button).

I have noticed that there are 3 `animationKey`s, which are contained in different childNodes of the node I instantiate:

- BBCharacter01AA_BoneLPlatform-Matrix-animation-transform
- BBCharacter01AA_BoneRPlatform-Matrix-animation-transform
- unnamed animation #2

I think the unnamed one is the general one, so I tried deleting that one, by using this on the child node that has the animation:

```
node.removeAnimation(forKey: "unnamed animation #2", blendOutDuration: 0)
```

When that didn't work, I tried deleting all animations I could find with `animationKeys`, but the model still animates.

I have also tried instantiating the animation separately and adding it by using a `CAAnimationGroup`, which has a `duration` of 0. I read that adding an animation with the same key should overwrite it, but that didn't seem to stop the animation either.

I truly am at a loss here, I have no idea what to try next.

Edit: I have tried the `removeAllAnimations` method on the `SCNNode` I instantiate. But that doesn't work either.

I have tried `sceneView.scene.isPaused = true`, and that finally works! I'm trying to jerryrig a way that uses the time when the model was added and the duration it was paused to try to align the updates to `isPaused` on the animation.